# Angular Material: Validation error on non form input

Tags: angularjs, angular-material

I would like to use Angular Material library in my project for showing the web page in Material design. I'm having input fields directly in a div, instead of having inside a **form** . How to properly do error validations now ?

Because the examples given on the documentation uses, **form** tag, which uses form name for showing ng-messages. How to achieve without form ?

Answer (score 0):

You may use the ng-form angular directive ([see docs here](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngForm)) to group anything, even outside a html form. Then, you can take advantage from angular FormController.

```
<div class="form-group" ng-form name="myForm">
    <input name="myInput" type="text" class="form-control" ng-model="bindTo" ng-maxlength="5">
    <span class="error" ng-show="myForm.myInput.$error.maxlength">Too long!</span>
</div>
```

[Example Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/29fRc4?p=preview)

Hope it helps